# SQL Server 2005 decimal field behaviour

Tags: sql-server

Ive create a simple table with a field x of type decimal(28,15)

I run the following query to insert a value:

> insert into testtable values (1234567890123)

when I do a select from testtable I, field x has a value of

> 1234567890123.000000000000000

Is there a way to specify (perhaps in the table design) that sql server should NOT store the zero's after the decimal if its not required? i.e. when doing a select the data will be returned as

> 1234567890123

Also why does insert into testtable values (12345678901234) give the following error :

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also why does insert into testtable values (12345678901234) give the following error :

You specified a total width of 28 with 15 digits after decimal point. That leaves at most 13 digits before decimal point.

> Is there a way to specify that sql server should NOT store the zero's after the decimal if its no required?

Strictly speaking, "decimal" is a fixed precision format and thus any number will occupy exactly the same space as any other number (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query . it works fine ...

```
   select cast(1234567890123.000000000000000 as decimal)
```